# Prolog - solving problems with lists

Tags: prolog

Hello I have to solve some prolog problems with lists but i can't figure it out how these work. 
I have to add "1" after every even element in a list, and to make the difference of 2 lists. 
I know this seems easy, in other language like java or c# i would make it very easy, but prolog it's giving me headaches.
Please help me :|

Comment: For the first problem: do you have to add 1 to a number or do you have to append "1" to a string. What is the type of your list elements? And for the second: how do you define "difference" between two lists? Do you mean that A - B = C (A, B, C are lists) where C[i] = A[i] - B[i]?

Comment: For me, when writing Prolog, it helps to think of rules that define what I want in natural language form initially. Usually, there are more than one. For example, "The result of inserting 1 after every even element in an EMPTY list is..." (and here you'd indicate if you want `[1]` or `[]`. Then you might have another rule that gives a recursive definition of what you want based upon the list's head and tail (`[H|T]`) or possibly two elements from the head and the tail (`[H1, H2|T]`). Then you translate the natural language into Prolog statements.

Comment: For the first one example: [4,3,5,7,2,6,3] -->[4,3,1,5,1,7,1,2,6,3,1] And the diferrence: A=[3,4,5,6,7], B=[4,7] --> C=[3,5,6]

Comment: Your example inserts a `1` after every odd element. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Could you please give the code, because these code snippets i found in other places too but i don't know how to put them together in prolog. Thanks!

Comment: Yes that is what i want. To insert 1 after every odd element

Comment: Whatever even or odd. It doesn't matter because what I don't know is how to create the other list.Even or odd is just about the condition i put when I check each elem. to see its type.

Comment: That seems to be a class assignment. Sorry to look like an old boring man but, before doing the homework, I would recommend you to first read your course notes and try to understand the easier examples your professor already gave you.

Answer (score 1):

Edited to note the clarified problem statement ("even item" meaning the item's value is even (rather than the item's ordinal position within the list):

```
insert_one_after_even_items( [] , [] ).             % if the source list is exhaused, we're done.
insert_one_after_even_items( [X|Xs] , [X,1|Ys] ) :- % otherwise, 
   0 is X mod 2 ,                                   % - if the number is even, prepend it and a 1 to the result list, and
   insert_one_after_even_items( Xs , Ys )           % - recurse down.
   .                                                %
insert_one_after_even_items( [X|Xs] , [X|Ys] ) :-   % otherwise,
   1 is X mod 2 ,                                   % - if the number is odd, prepend it to the result list, and
   insert_one_after_even_items( Xs , Ys )           % - recurse down.
   .                                                % Easy!
```

For your second problem, producing the difference between two lists, are you talking about set differences? If so, given two sets A and B, are you talking about the relative difference (all elements of A that do not exist in B), or the absolute difference (all elements of either A or B that do not exist in both sets)?

To solve the relative set difference problem (Find all members of A that do not also exist in B), you can use the built-in `member/2` predicate:

```
relative_difference( [] , _ , [] ) .          % if the source list is exhausted, we're done
relative_difference( [A|As] , Bs , R ) :-     % if the source list is non-empty, and
  member(A,Bs) ,                              % - the current A is an element of B,
  ! ,                                         % - we insert a deterministic cut (no backtracking)
  relative_difference( As , Bs , R )          % - and recurse down, discarding the current A
  .                                           %
relative_difference( [A|As] , Bs , [A|R] ) :- % if the source list is non-empty (and A is not an element of B due to the cut inserted earlier)
  relative_difference( As , Bs , R )          % we simply add A to the result list and recurse down.
  .
```

One thing you will note here: we are building the result list in all of these examples is built from a variable. The tail of the list is unbound (and passed as the new result to the next recursive call, where it either become a new list node or, at the very end, the empty list.

This has the effect of

- building the list in order (rather than in reverse order).
- if the result was bound on the initial call, unification against the expected result occurs item by item as the recursion proceeds, which means
- execution is short-circuited when the first unification failure occurs.

If your prolog implementation doesn't have `member/2` as a built in, it's easy enough to implement. Something like this ought to do it:

```
member(X,[X|T]) :- ! .           % A hit! cut and succeed.
member(X,[_|T]) :- member(X,T) . % ... and a miss. Just recurse down on the tail.
```

Comment: it works thanks, but could you please explain me what have done there?Where did you check if the nr. is even?

Comment: For the second one I mean relative difference

Comment: @jojuk: see my amended answer.

Comment: In the second one, it gives me an error. If I declare "member" in the predicates section it says that I have no clause for that predicate, and if I don't declare it it says that is undeclared. What should I do?

Comment: What prolog are you using? You may need to import a lists module (see you documentation for details. Or you can roll your own (that's a good exercise). Some rules: An object, X, is not a member of the empty list. X is a member of the list if the head of the list can be unified with X. In any other case, discard the head of the list and recurse down on the tail. That's about all there is to it. You'll probably need to use the cut operator (!), to introduce determinism.

Comment: I'm using Turbo Prolog. Is it ok if I write like this member(_,[]). member(elem,[H,T]):- !,member(elem,T).

Comment: It works ! Thank you for the help you gave me, and for all the patience :)